# А возможно ли подменять буквы

Tags: python, текст

И так, как сделать так, чтобы определённые буквы заменялись, например буквы

```
T, t = 7, 7
V, v = \/, \/
W, w = \v/, \v/
Z, z = 2, 2
L, l = 1, 1
I, i = |, |
G, g = 6, 6
D, d = [), [)
C, c = (, (
```

вот как должно это выглядеть
`Hello, my name is Liquid, bruh client` `He11o, my name |s 1|qu|[), bruh (1|en7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например через функцию строки `replace`, или через генерацию новой строки с подменой символов, или через функцию строки `translate`:

1. Для алгоритма с `replace` проходим по словарю и вызываем замену ключа на значение
2. При генерации новой строки, перебирая символы запрашиваем значение по ключу и если ключа не будет, вернется сам символ, такая логика в `.get(c, c)`
3. Для использования функции строки `translate` нужна таблица, которую получим через `maketrans` использя словарь с ассоциацией символов, а дальше вызываем метод

Для удобства работы, оформил ассоциацию символов в виде словаря. А для проверки работы использовал оператор `assert`

Пример:

```
CHAR_BY_REPLACED = {
    'T': '7', 't': '7',
    'V': r'\/', 'v': r'\/',
    'W': r'\v/', 'w': r'\v/',
    'Z': '2', 'z': '2',
    'L': '1', 'l': '1',
    'I': '|', 'i': '|',
    'G': '6', 'g': '6',
    'D': '[)', 'd': '[)',
    'C': '(', 'c': '(',
}


def using_replace(text: str) -> str:
    for c1, c2 in CHAR_BY_REPLACED.items():
        text = text.replace(c1, c2)
    return text


def create_new_string(text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(CHAR_BY_REPLACED.get(c, c) for c in text)


def using_translate(text: str) -> str:
    trans_table = str.maketrans(CHAR_BY_REPLACED)
    return text.translate(trans_table)


text = 'Hello, my name is Liquid, bruh client'
expected = 'He11o, my name |s 1|qu|[), bruh (1|en7'

print(using_replace(text))
assert using_replace(text) == expected

print(create_new_string(text))
assert create_new_string(text) == expected

print(using_translate(text))
assert using_translate(text) == expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Частично так

```
astring='abc'
alist=bytearray(astring,encoding='utf')
alist[0]=ord('A')
#Abc
```

Всегда като-так

```
def repl(string,num,char):
   return string[0,num-1]+char+string[num,-1]
```